# Find degradation rate on a scatterplot

Tags: time-series, curve-fitting, scatterplot, quality-control

I work for a commercial printing company, and am collecting data regarding the quality of our printing over time (density and dot gains).  Essentially, for every job I have a date, a density, and a dot gain.  I would like to be able to analyze a date range and check to see if our quality seems to be getting consistently worse.

From a math perspective, I somewhat understand what I need to do.  I need to get a best fit curve for our data, and then find the derivative of that curve.  The slope of that derivative should give some insight as to if our quality is getting better or worse, and how quickly.

My biggest hiccup here is how to find the best fit curve for a scatter plot.  Certainly I can work out a way to find the derivative after that, but I can't think of any good way to find the original curve.

So - how do you find the best fit curve of a scatter plot?  And bonus points if you can give me a quick and (relatively) easy way to get the derivative/slope of that curve.

Comment: Hi there, is there any QA process that is undertaken that you will need to take into account, e.g. recalibration, machine servicing?

Comment: @Michelle Yes, there is, but the assumption is that while this data is being viewed, we will recognize that large positive spikes in quality will correlate with some sort of machine servicing.  Often times those things take thousands of dollars or days of work, so the management that will be viewing this data will be quite aware of when it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are density and dot gain both measures of quality?  Are they highly correlated?  If yes and yes it might be easier to create a single quality index and see what happens to that over time.

Whatever the answer to that, it sounds like you want something like [locally weighted scatterplot smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression).  There is a good implementation in R (free) and in some commercial stats packages.  This technique would be effective if what you are most worried about is a locally consistent downwards trend (where "local" means recent observations).

Answer (score 1):

If you have many time points, you could look at some time series analysis methods. If relatively few, then maybe a two regressions with spline curves for time (the independent variable) and each measure of quality as the dependent variable.